# li items won't be display as it should

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple navbar, the parent container is position relative, and the child is absolute, but all the li items just stack in to eachother in a pile of lump.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #eee;
}


.navbarMenu {
 width: 100%;
 background-color:#fff;
 position: relative;
}
.navbarMenu li {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbarMenu">
  <li><a href="#">Display</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Float</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">flexbox</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: all list-items are absolutely positioned 5px from the right as you defined: what's the expected result?

Comment: I just want to move all of the li items a little to the right inside the navbar

Comment: remove absolute positioning and put text-align right on the ul.  You should probably have a read up on positioning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position - you have defined all li to sit 5px from the right side of the ul - which is why they stack

Comment: so there's no need to use position absolute; just set a margin-left to list-items to move them a bit to the right: or set a padding left on their container.

Comment: easiest way put away `position: absolute`and in `.navbarMenu{text-align: right;}

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `absolute` positioning and replaced `right` with `margin-left`. This apply's a margin to the elements relative to one another which I think is your desired result:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aQZZVd

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #eee;
}

.navbarMenu {
 width: 100%;
 background-color:#fff;
 position: relative;
}
.navbarMenu li {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbarMenu">
  <li><a href="#">Display</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Float</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">flexbox</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

As others have mentioned, you should definitely take the time to understand the differences between relative and absolute positioning.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: What's the easiest way to go if i want to cramp the list items  more tigther, like twitters navbar?

Comment: Please put the code in the actual answer - links may die and then this will be of no use to future users

Answer (score 0):

I would like to put them more close like it is on twitters navbar.

What's the easiest way to do this?

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #eee;
}

.navbarMenu {
 width: 100%;
 background-color:#fff;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px;
}

.navbarMenu li  {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 160px;
 padding: 2px;
 
}
a:hover {
 color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbarMenu">
  <li><a href="#">Display</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Float</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">flexbox</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks like a separate question. You should open a new question for that. I'm not sure I understand the question but I think you want to reduce the `margin-left` of your `.navbarMenu li` to something like `30px` instead of `160px`